# android listview to table layout

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi im having trouble printing list of items from listview to a table.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String filename = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.FileName)).getText().toString();
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_FILENAME, filename);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
```

from first page when item is clicked, it will get passed onto the second page.

in the second page when 2 items are checked, I want to print the result to the table but error comes up. help!!!

```
if(checkedItems == 2){
        Intent in1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TableActivity.class);
        String filename = ((TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.FileName)).getText().toString();
        in1.putExtra(KEY_FILENAME, filename);
        startActivity(in1);
    }
```

logCat looks like this

06-21 16:02:57.011: D/dalvikvm(422): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2120 objects / 142168 bytes in 43ms
06-21 16:02:59.931: D/AndroidRuntime(422): Shutting down VM
06-21 16:02:59.931: W/dalvikvm(422): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.xml.android.QuestionActivity.onItemClick(QuestionActivity.java:119)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-21 16:02:59.941: E/AndroidRuntime(422):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 16:03:36.252: D/AndroidRuntime(447): Shutting down VM
06-21 16:03:36.262: W/dalvikvm(447): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xml.android/com.xml.android.TableActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at com.xml.android.TableActivity.onCreate(TableActivity.java:27)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-21 16:03:36.272: E/AndroidRuntime(447):  ... 11 more

Comment: in intent use activity context like Intent in = new Intent(<Your current activity name>.this,QuestionActivity.class);

Comment: log cat please to confirm .......................

Comment: Your error lies in the `onCreate()` in the TableActivity class. So if you can post that class(or at least its `onCreate()`), it would be easier to point out the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
intnt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuestionActivity.class));
String filename = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.FileName)).getText().toString()
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();   
bundle.putString(KEY_FILENAME, filename);
intnt.putExtras(bundle); 
startActivity(intnt);


// In the receiving class write

Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String name1 = b.getString("KEY_FILENAME");
```

Answer (score 1):

create intents like this

```
Intent in = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
in.putExtra(KEY_FILENAME, filename);
startActivity(in);
```